# Spring Boot properties file between develop phase and 'production' phase

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have developed a simple **Spring Boot** application (not a web but a **standalone one**).

Inside my app I use a custom '**user.properties**' file which properties like:

```
smtp.host=<development.somesmtp.host>
```

The ejecutable jar file that contains the packaged application includes that 'user.properties' file.

BUT, if the user of my application whants to change that property, he cant's because the properties file is inside the jar.

```
smtp.host=<production.somesmtp.host>
```

What is the correct way to approach this issue?

Comment: Now if only Spring Boot would support [Externalizing Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

1. Use this annotations:

   @Component
   @PropertySource({"file:C:/PRONOM/user.properties", "classpath:user.properties"})
   public class UserProperties {
2. Launch the app with the next command:

   java -jar C:/PRONOM/pronom-0.0.1.jar --spring.config.location=file:C:/PRONOM/user.properties